# Reuse JWT from Azure AD between WPF and angular

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, single-sign-on, adal.js

I have a WPF client application who uses our Azure AD to authenticate users. Is it possibe to pass the JWT token from the WPF app to an angular application and use it to authenticate users?

I want to achive that users do not need to sign in twice. I want to somehow reauthenticate the user in the angular application based on the information retrived when authentication was made in the WPF app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be. When calling the app, you can include the JWT token in the request, and prepare the app to validate it (in this case, against the Azure AD authority, I would say). You certainly have several examples/sources you can follow, like [this one](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/).

I don't know if you are using [OpenId Connect with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oidc), but given your use case, it could be a good option :)

Comment: Is there also possible to refresh the token if it has expired in the angular app? Without having the user to re enter credentials?

Comment: Yes, the OIDC provides the concept of refresh tokens. Please, check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect)